# How to sort solrdocumentlist object

Tags: java, sorting, solr, lucene

In fact, me need some solution for random sorting in this case. I tried to sort by `Collections`

```
SolrDocumentList randSolrDocs = Collections.shuffle(solrDocList)
```

But received an error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to SolrDocumentList`.

Please, help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collections.shuffle(solrDocList)` shuffles the list that you pass as a parameter. The method has no return value.

So after the call, `solrDocList` is randomized.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its my terrible inattention